# How to increase numbers from loaded file - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I have created a code that read a specific column of text from file. File content looks something like this:

```
1
12
3
8
```

etc.

---

my php code:

```
<?php

$array = file('test.tsv');
$liczba = 3;

foreach ($array as $line) {

    $line_array = explode("\t", $line);
    $new_array[] = $line_array[15].'</br>';

}

echo implode($new_array);


?>
```

And now I want to increase this numbers by $liczba. but I don't know how to do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing would be to try and then come back here with your code if it isn't working... Basically I think it would be more optimal to write your updated input into a string, then have this string written in a text file

Comment: Your example data is just one number on each line, but in your code you are splitting each line at a tab character – how is that supposed to make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_array[] = ($line_array[15] + $liczba) .'</br>';
```